# Security, hardening and NAT for RTP and SIP

Tags: proxy, asterisk, voip, sip, rtp

I decided to create a VOIP server and it has gotten more complicated then I thought it would. So in order to make my server more secure, I keep it behind a pfSense appliance. I use IP filtering to reduce my online availability to only our remote office locations (all in NYC). I get this impending feeling people will want to access the server via their cell phones and check voicemail via the portal offsite. So I was thinking of some kind of reverse proxy with an authentication like a SOCKS as opposed a VPN which just is not practical with the variety of devices people use.From my understanding creating an outbound proxy would only proxify the SIP and NOT the RTP. The issue is also that it goes Asterisk>1:1 w/ pfSense>Internet>Firewall w/ NAT>SIP Phone. Will using the NAT be an issue? What are other people doing? Does anyone have a similar situation? What should I google?

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk already has builtin methods to handle NAT related issues. Take a look at [this](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions) article.

If you still wan't to proxify, you can try [SaRP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sarp/), which seems to work for both SIP and RTP.